# Set combobox to the value of another combobox - Access Vba

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have 2 combo boxes on a Form. `ComboID` and `ComboName`

ComboID contains items such as 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004 etc...
ComboName contains items such as John, Matt, David, Luke etc...

I have a table with this data:
1001, John
1002, Matt
1003, David
1004, Luke

I want `ComboID` to display `1001` when I select `John` from `ComboName`.
And I also want `ComboName` to display '1002' when I select `Matt`.

I need to be able to select a new Name or ID at any point and have its corresponding value update in the other combo-box.

I'm stuck with trying to get this to work and it can't be as hard as I'm making it out to be. I am still learning VBA code. Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First Glance Solution (not recommended)

### What it Was

My initial reaction to this problem was to try and use a [change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211341%28v=office.11%29.aspx). Setting up subroutines for each combobox to change the value of the other combobox would have then been the solution.

### Why you shouldn't use it

However, in the documentation for the Access vba change events (link above) it clearly states:

> "Avoid creating two or more controls having Change events that affect each other — for example, two text boxes that update each other" ([msdn access vba change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211341%28v=office.11%29.aspx))

Unfortunately, this is exactly what you would be doing using the change event solution (using comboboxes instead of text boxes). In your example, a change in the ComboID combobox would trigger the appropriate change in the ComboName combobox, but that change in the ComboName combobox would trigger an attempted change in the ComboID, and this loop could continue on. Therefore, this is not a good answer to your problem.

## A Better Solution

An [AfterUpdate Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211226%28v=office.11%29.aspx) appears to be the more appropriate approach to use in this case.

### Why the problematic loop won't be triggered

As mentioned in the AfterUpdate documentation:

> Changing data in a control by using Visual Basic or a macro containing the SetValue action doesn't trigger these events for the control.

Therefore, an AfterUpdate Event (possibly using a [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210617%28v=office.11%29.aspx))  should be a much better approach.

Much thanks to @Remou for pointing out the error of my change event ways and bringing the AfterUpdate event to my attention.

Comment: I am not sure because I don't know what that would look like in VBA. Am I on the right track? When I had it set to OnClick() I was getting an error. Now I don't get anything.

Private Sub ComboID_OnChange()
    Me.ComboName.Text = ?
End Sub

Private Sub ComboName_OnChange()
    Me.ComboID.Text = ?
End Sub

Comment: @user1946392 Yes, you're on the right track. A simple 1 line solution for obtaining the value would be to use [DLookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx) It would be like `Me.ComboName.value = Dlookup("NameField","yourTable","IDField = " & Me.ComboID.value)`

Comment: Thank you so much this has helped a lot so far. But the fields are not updating each other correctly. When I select an ID, the Name box goes blank and when I select a Name, the ID box goes blank. This will work for our purposes but it would be nice if the ID and Name fields matched up. Thank You!!

Private Sub SearchID_Change()
    Me.SearchName.Value = DLookup("SubjectID", "Master Hearing Data", "SubjectID = " & Me.SearchID.Value)
    
End Sub

Private Sub SearchName_Change()
    Me.SearchID.Value = DLookup("SubjectID", "Master Hearing Data", "SubjectID = " & Me.SearchName.Value)
    
End Sub

Comment: I would not use a change event except for special, exceptional reasons. An after update event is much more suitable for combos. I am afraid this is not a good answer, but I see you are fairly new to the site.

Comment: @Remou Thanks. I appreciate the clarification. Is deleting my answer the appropriate thing for me to do now?

Comment: Absolutely not! Just add a few details. Make use of any hints in my answer. It is proper to improve your answer on SO. :)

Answer (score 2):

**A change event is very rarely a suitable choice for code**. For example, a combobox allows the user to type as well as to select items, so the change event will fire for every single character typed. As will any events that are chained to that event, leading to the possibility of horrible complications.

Set up the combo boxes like so, thought it is a bit of a mystery as to why you wish to do this. You may need to keep them in synch in the current event. You do not mention if the combos are bound to a Control Source, so I have not included one.

ComboID

```
RowSource: SELECT ID, [Name] FROM Table ORDER BY ID
BoundColumn: 1 
ColumnCount: 2
ColumnWidths: 2cm;0cm ''The second column is hidden,
                      ''the first column is any width

Private Sub ComboID_AfterUpdate()
    Me.ComboName = Me.ComboID
End Sub
```

ComboName

```
RowSource: SELECT ID, [Name] FROM Table ORDER BY [Name]
BoundColumn: 1
ColumnCount: 2
ColumnWidths: 0cm;2cm ''The first column is hidden, 
                      ''the second column is any width

Private Sub ComboName_AfterUpdate()
    Me.ComboID = Me.ComboName
End Sub
```